# RecyclerView onClick not working properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView in my fragment to show images with text in Grid format,the Recycler view grid_item.xml look like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin_grid"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using adapter to populate data in RecyclerView, the code for this is :

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    private Context context;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addItems(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {

        this.movies.addAll(movies);

    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_grid_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.title.setText(movies.get(i).getTitle());
        Picasso.with(context).load(movies.get(i).getImage_url_medium()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView title;
        private ImageView thumbnail;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // Handles the row being being clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition(); // gets item position
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) { // Check if an item was deleted, but the user clicked it before the UI removed it
                Movie movie = movies.get(position);
                // start detail activity
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MovieDetail.class);
                i.putExtra(Constants.MOVIES_OBJECT, movie);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

My problem is click listener is only working on the TextView and not on the image , although I have set click listener on whole view which contains both image and text.Is something wrong with my implementation ?

Comment: try to implement onclicklistner on CardView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to your imageview.
and remove `android:clickable="true"` or set it to false

Answer (score 3):

Use `viewHolder.itemView` like :

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //your action
        });
```

This will enable click action on whole `RecyclerView` item.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to the root `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin_grid"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

public class OffersRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Activity mActivity;
private List<OfferShopModel> offerShopModels = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> allColors = new ArrayList<String>();


public OffersRecycleViewAdapter(List<OfferShopModel> offerShopModels, Activity activity, ArrayList<String> allColors) {
    this.offerShopModels = offerShopModels;
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

// String[] allColors = mActivity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_offers, viewGroup, false);

    return new ItemViewHolder(v);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, final int position) {

    itemViewHolder.mOffer.setText(offerShopModels.get(position).getOffer());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return offerShopModels.size();
}

class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView mLinearLayoutBack;
    TextView mOffer;

    ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mOffer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer);        
        mOffer.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

  // call click event

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:clickable="true"` from your `ImageView` or change it to `android:clickable="false"`